# GCP manage kubernetes autodeploy image path

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

In my project on GCP i setup an autmatedodeploy for a specific deploy on my kubernetes cluster, ath the end of procedure an image path like:

```
gcr.io/direct-variety-325450/cc-mirror:$COMMIT_SHA
```

was create.
If i see in my GCP "Container Registry" i se images wit tag like  c15c5019183ded74814d570a9a33d2f95ecdfb32

Now my question is:
How can i in my deployment.yaml file specify the latest image name if there are no latest or other tag?

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    - name: django
      image: ????
...
```

if i put:

```
gcr.io/direct-variety-325450/cc-mirror:$COMMIT_SHA
```

or:

```
gcr.io/direct-variety-325450/cc-mirror
```

i get an Error:

> Cannot download Image, Image does not exist

What i have to put into my image: entry of deployment.yaml?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Comment: Are you able to pull it manually using the first one. Also I hope the COMMIT is getting substituted with the actual value

Comment: Hi if i use <image>:<tag> yes but tag change every ush and in kubernetes deployments.yaml file i cannot know the latest tag

Comment: You would have to supply it somehow , maybe push the latest image as latest along with pushing it with the tag. Or before running the deploy you would need to query the registry to get the latest tag present and then supply it to the yaml file

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You need to specify the latest tag in your deployment.

In fact, Kubernetes automates a lot of thing for you. You tell what you want, Kubernetes compares its state with your wishes and perform actions.

If you don't specify the image tag, kubernetes will compare your wish (no tag) with the current state of the cluster (no tag) and because it's equal, it will do nothing.

---

Now how to automate the new tag deployment. Here no magic: you need a placeholder in your deployment.yaml file and to execute a sed in your file to replace the placeholder by the real value.

And then apply the change on this updated file.